# Plot points with different colours based on different numbers from a column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data set that consists of lat, long and "Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35". The name should remain the same so that everyone can apply it to the data set later.

```
   Latitude Longitude Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35
   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>                           
 1 8.983    51.733    1                               
 2 44.3498  -30.267   8                               
 3 50.9332  -41.75    94                              
 4 36.1333  -68.9167  1                               
 5 35.7833  -68.9333  1                               
 6 37.65    -72.95    6                               
 7 35.7667  -69.0833  1                               
 8 39.1332  -42.65    2                               
 9 5.2833   -17.0667  1                               
10 3.65     -18.3     1
```

As you can see, the column "Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35" varies with entries between 1 and 93. Now I want to display all locations where "Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35" occurs, where 1-5 should be coloured blue 5-10 green 10-20 light green etc. until >90 should be displayed as red... how can I do this? the code is based on everything:

```
install.packages("ggOceanMaps")
install.packages('ggspatial')
install.packages("ggrepel")
install.packages("readr")
library(ggrepel)
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggspatial)
library(readr)




map <- basemap(c(-180, 180, -90, 90), bathymetry = TRUE)+
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)
  ) 

print(map)
```

Comment: Just specify `color = Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35` inside `aes`, but you should probably convert it to numeric first, otherwise you will end up with 100 different colors. Then you can specify whatever color scale you like using the various ggplot color scale functions. There are literally hundreds of examples on this site. Try typing "scale_color_gradient" in the search bar at the top of this page.

Comment: Thank you for your Kind answer! But how do i convert it to numeric? Im quite Bad and new at coding

Comment: there are lots and lots of resources for R freely available on the internet (including on this site). A simple search for "How do I convert a character to numeric in R" will easily reveal the answer (it's `color = as.numeric(Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35)`). Stack Overflow is a good place to _find_ answers to basic programming questions that have already been asked, but it doesn't really work as a forum for asking about the basics when that information is already available or has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add an example, although very useful comments already have been added to this question. It is not a perfect solution, but it adds the colors which can be adjusted to whatever scale needed.

```
# load libraries
library(ggrepel)
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggspatial)
library(readr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create a data frame with random values since I do not have your dataset
my_data <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(-180:180, 10, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(-90:90, 10, replace = TRUE),
  var3 = sample(-180:180, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

# Print the resulting data frame to check the content
print(my_data)


# plot map, see part with col = ... and scale_colour_gradientn
map <- basemap(c(-180, 180, -90, 90), bathymetry = TRUE)+
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = my_data, aes(x = var1, y = var2, cex = 8, col = var3)
  ) + scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "green", "orange", "red"))

print(map)
```

[image: Output of the code above.]